# Hide and show elements on button click w/ .hide()?

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to find how to hide and show a set of paragraphs using jQuery. I want to find a way to do this using the same button, and with .hide() and .show(). I don't know if this is possible or 'correct', but I'm relatively new to javascript am trying to teach myself.

Here is a fiddle showing what I've done so far: http://jsfiddle.net/GAa23/

My problem here is that I can get it to hide, but I cannot get the button to show the elements on the second click.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var btn = 1;
var advancebtn = function () {
    btn++;
};

var reducebtn = function () {
    btn--;
};

if (btn >= 1) {
    $("button").click(function () {
        reducebtn();
        $("p").hide();
    });
} else {
    $("button").click(function () {
        advancebtn();
        $("p").show();
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Toggle is what you want but your event handling is inside out

Comment: I've learned how to use toggle, but I was wondering if there was any way to do it with show and hide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the problem is that **you never run** the second click event handler. You code runs on page ready and the if statement `if (btn >= 1) {` does not go to else.

Try this instead:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("p").toggle();
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5cqW/)

**Or**, put the if statement inside the click handler:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    if (btn >= 1) {
        reducebtn();
        $("p").hide();
    } else {
        advancebtn();
        $("p").show();
    }
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5cqW/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Put your if/else inside the click event, otherwise you're only hooking up the hide handler.

```
$("button").click(function () {
    if (btn >= 1) {
        reducebtn();
        $("p").hide();
    } else {
        advancebtn();
        $("p").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is show/hide the <p> try

```
$("button").click(function() {
   $("p").toggle(); 
});
```

You can also add animation to the toggle with `$("p").toggle("slow");` or `$("p").toggle("fast");`

Using your specific example by using show(); and hide(); and the logic I think you want to implement:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    if (btn >= 1) {
        reducebtn();
        $("p").hide();
    } else {
        advancebtn();
        $("p").show();
    }
});
```